# Metropolis-Hastings algorithm for a completely specified distribution

Tags: bayesian, sampling, markov-chain-montecarlo, metropolis-hastings, mcmc-acceptance-rate

Consider a random variable $X\sim f(x)$, such that
$$
f(x)=\frac{1}{c}\times K(x)\propto K(x),
$$
where c: normalizing constant, K(x): the kernel of the distribution (ie the part which involves $x$). $f$ is unknown and complicated, in the sense that it does not resemble any known distribution.

The M-H algorithm is designed to simulate from $f$ based only on the kernel $K(x)$, which makes its application rather complicated. I wonder how easy the M-H algorithm would become if we know the normalizing constant $c$?

Comment: This does not bring any information on how to simulate $f$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Well, it depends on the actual kernel. For instance, provided I know $c$, I could use inverse transform sampling (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling) instead of M-H. This can be achieved by some numerical integration method. But if I still need to use MH, how that information would help me? that was my question.

Comment: However, the normalization constant will not cancel out on the M-H?

Comment: Since the question is about M-H, my answer remains that knowing the constant $c$ is not helping.

Comment: Fiodor, I am afraid so, so we shall conclude that MH is not the best choice in this case, since it does not make any difference to know the constant. Thanks all.

Comment: See also the answers to https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/307940/7224

Comment: A side usage of $c$ would be to exploit it as a control variate, i.e., a function whose expectation is known, but this does not help in designing a better Metropolis-Hastings algorithm.